# How to remove special character from a folder name?

Tags: bash, unix, script

I am creating a folder like

```
mkdir -p ../service/target/static
```

but windows creates it with some special character `static`. I need to explicitely remove that special character using shell script.
I tried with rn and mv commands but doesn't seem to work and rename command giving error command not found.

Comment: You said "but windows creates it...", well if your running Windows... then this is not the appropriate place for your question. That said, you should always use quotes, single or doubles as appropriate, to avoid any problems. e.g.: `mkdir -p '../service/target/static'`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with quotes.

Comment: Is the `mkdir` command in a shell script? If so, the script might have DOS/Windows-style line endings, which include a carriage return character that the unix shell will treat as part of the command line (and in this case, part of the filename). See [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings).

Comment: dos2unix worked for me.

Comment: So you are saying `mv static? staticx` would not change the special character to the letter `x`?

Comment: No. The issue was what @gordon mentioned. After l used dos2unix command on that script file it didn't g generate any special characters.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW. Below is a simple script to rename a file(or directory).

```
> cat rename-file
#!/bin/bash
source=$1
target=`echo "$source" | sed -e 's/[^A-Za-z0-9._-]/_/g'`
if [ "$source" != "$target" ]; then
    mv "$source" "$target"
fi
```

For example (go to the directory, write the command and tab-expand the filename)

```
> ls -1
'a\b(c#d@e'
> rename-file a\\b\(c#d@e
> ls -1
a_b_c_d_e
```

You might want to fit the translation to your needs.

```
s/[^A-Za-z0-9._-]/_/g
```