# Pipe to mv command

Tags: terminal, command-line, unix

I'm trying to move files from Terminal but only those from the results of a `grep` query.

```
ls -l | grep -i s02 | mv
```

What is the best way to complete the command above?

Comment: Where do you want to mv the files to?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can accomplish this by just running

```
cd directory/containing/the/files
mv *[sS]02* /path/to/target/
```

For more complex operations there is also the option to use `find` to find all relevant files. The example from your question could also be written as

```
cd directory/containing/the/files
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -iname '*s02*' -exec mv {} /path/to/target/directory/ \;
```

It's worth to have a look at `man find` to see which other options are available.

Comment: Along time ago someone told me that regular expressions  match strings and globs match/generate filenames. Possibly, man 3 glob may help.

Answer (score 1):

For example with bash. Given the files below

```
$ ls -1
test1
test2
test3
```

1) To avoid surprises let's take a look at the commands first

```
$ for i in test*; do echo mv $i $i.ext; done
mv test1 test1.ext
mv test2 test2.ext
mv test3 test3.ext
```

and execute the commands if this is what we want

```
$ for i in test*; do mv $i $i.ext; done
$ ls -1
test1.ext
test2.ext
test3.ext
```

Fit the path to your needs.

2) It is possible to use *sed* and *xargs*. Let's test it first

```
$ ls -1 test* | sed 'p;s/test/test_/' | xargs -n2 printf "%s %s\n"
test2 test_2
test1 test_1
test3 test_3
```

and execute the commands if this is what we want

```
$ ls -1 test* | sed 'p;s/test/test_/' | xargs -n2 mv
$ ls -1
test_1
test_2
test_3
```

**Spaces in the filename**

These scripts won't work as expected if the filenames include spaces. In Unix space is used as a separator. For example with the files

```
$ ls -1
test 1
test 2
test 3
```

it is clear that the commands below can't work as expected

```
$ for i in test*; do echo mv $i $i.ext; done
mv test 1 test 1.ext
mv test 2 test 2.ext
mv test 3 test 3.ext
```

The solution is to exclude the space from the list of separators

```
$ IFS="`printf '\n\t'`"
```

and prepend it to the commands that should process the filenames with spaces. The command below

```
$ IFS="`printf '\n\t'`"; for i in test*; do mv $i $i.ext; done
```

works as expected

```
$ ls -1
test 1.ext
test 2.ext
test 3.ext
```

Next option is the quotation of the arguments

```
for i in test*; do mv "$i" "$i.ext"; done
```

This way it's possible to use the rich variety of Unix filters and avoid the limitation to the "find ... -exec ... {}" construct. For other limitations see the notes under the line.

**Notes on macOS**

1) Quoting from [opengroup.org - Product Standard: Commands and Utilities V4](http://www.opengroup.org/csq/repository/noreferences=1&RID=apple%252FCX1%25252F11.html)

> 1.4.21 sh
>   Question 31: Is the environment variable IFS ignored when the shell is invoked?
>   Response: Yes
>   Rationale: The specification allows the sh command ignore the setting of the IFS environment variable on invocation. The setting of this variable has been used to breach security on systems which use the shell to interpret a call to the system() and execvp() interfaces.
>   Reference: Technical Standard, Shell and Utilities, Issue 6, Chapter 4, Utilities, sh, ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES, IFS.

2) Quoting from [developer.apple.com - Shell Input and Output](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/OpenSource/Conceptual/ShellScripting/ShellInputandOutput/ShellInputandOutput.html)

> You can modify the behavior of the read command by modifying the shell variable IFS (short for internal field separators). The default behavior is to split inputs everywhere there is a space, tab, or newline. By changing this variable, ...

3) Quoting from [developer.apple.com - Basic Control Statements - Standard for Loops](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/OpenSource/Conceptual/ShellScripting/FlowControl,Expansion,andParsing/FlowControl,Expansion,andParsing.html)

> In the next example, the list is *.JPG ...

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in *.JPG ; do
    mv "$i" "$(echo $i | sed 's/\.JPG$/.x/')"
    mv "$(echo $i | sed 's/\.JPG$/.x/')" "$(echo $i | sed 's/\.JPG$/.jpg/')"
done
```

---

<sup>These scripts may not work as expected if there are special characters in the filename. Replace such characters first. See [How to remove special character](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/353860/how-to-remove-special-character-from-a-folder-name/). There are dozens of articles how to rename files with spaces and other characters that make troubles e.g. [Filenames with spaces breaking for loop, find command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343727/filenames-with-spaces-breaking-for-loop-find-command). It's a good idea to get rid of such characters and translate the filenames to the format you prefer (e.g.
[rename-file](https://github.com/vbotka/utils/blob/master/rename-file)) before processing them in *nix. See [Fixing Unix/Linux/POSIX Filenames](https://dwheeler.com/essays/fixing-unix-linux-filenames.html).</sup>

Comment: This will fail with filenames like `test 1` and similar. It will also not do what you expect it to do if the current directory contains files with names starting with `test`.

Comment: Renaming is not necessary, making sure to use options/tools which ensure `\0`-terminated strings and taking care of setting/using variables is all it takes. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ :-)

Comment: Well, IMHO it's more secure, efficient and flexible to get rid of pathological filenames and don't care about the pitfalls i.e. to normalize the filenames ASAP and process them later. [Security](https://dwheeler.com/essays/fixing-unix-linux-filenames.html) and  [Modularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy) is all it takes.

Comment: Thanks for the links, but maybe people should focus on learning how a system works and not how it is wrong. If shell scripts or programs break on file names containing characters which the file system (and the standard) allow those scripts/programs are simply broken and need to be fixed.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what people should focus on. Feel free to test [rename-file](https://github.com/vbotka/utils/blob/master/rename-file) and report [issues](https://github.com/vbotka/utils/issues).

Comment: @VladimirBotka I work mostly on macOS, so spaces in filenames are a normal and common thing. I'd argue they'll be common anywhere files are mostly created/used via a GUI rather than a command line.

Comment: Over the years, I found people do what is allowed not what makes sense when it comes to computers. Since unix does allow a space in a file, it's best to code for the space. Wikipedia does include macOS in it's list of Unix derivatives.  Apples was saying macOS is built on rock solid Unix.

Comment: @Gordon Davisson: The question is tagged "Unix" hence the answer is not "macOS" specific. I've added the section on how to process filenames with spaces. You are right that such filenames are common, but this is not a reason to put the spaces into the filenames when I don't have to. Spaces in filenames is the other part of the world created by MS. No one in *nix world would ever use it voluntarily which is clear from [Probably too late for an outright ban on spaces in filenames](https://dwheeler.com/essays/fixing-unix-linux-filenames.html).

Comment: @Vladimir Botka Where is the documentation?

Comment: @historystamp: We are not in contradiction. Yes, people can do what is allowed. I can't prevent if someone wants to shoot in his leg. Yes,  it's best to code for the space. Still the same, my preference is to avoid spaces mainly for security. Yes, macOS is a UNIX derivative. There are many differences among Unix derivatives. Don't hesitate to tag it properly. (I wonder what might be the reason to defend such obvious nonsense like spaces in the filenames. What is the advantage to have a space in the filename instead of for example an underscore?)

Comment: @VladimirBotka Spaces in file names match natural language and predate Unix so it is not a MS thing. Basically if your tools make spaces insecure then you have poor tools. Use a ;decent; scripting language e.g. AppleScript VB, python perl tcl scheme etc. not a porr one like sh etc.

Comment: @Mark: Good point that you mentioned *sh*. It's the common shell among the systems and [Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/shell/sh.html#sh-posix-shell-bin-sh) decided to make it the default shell for cross-platform system magement with over 1000 [modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/list_of_all_modules.html#all-modules) including iosxr_* modules. A system that was very probably one of the reasons why IBM bought RH for $34bn. Don't be mistaken you want to use the same poor tools like me.

Comment: Sorry to say, the solution for the spaces issues is not the change the value of IFS. The solution is to *not* use a `for` loop over the the result of `find`. Using `find ... -exec` (combined with `xargs` and/or `sh -c`) is the canonical Unix way of doing these kind of things.

Comment: There is no such thing as "the canonical Unix way". Maybe it is for macOS. The Unix paradigm is, "Tools, Not Policy!" Btw. this is the difference we're talking about from the very beginning.

Comment: Re: `spaces in filenames are a normal and common thing`. For the record: Filenames with spaces are considered [UNUSUAL FILENAMES](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) in Unix.